# Serological assays not detecting native proteins

Tags: botany, assay-development

Is there anyone out there who has done much work with serological assays? We have antiserum for a manufactured viral protein but no luck so far getting it to detect native protein (unless today's attempt worked which we will find out tomorrow).

What are any common problems or possible considerations that we should bear in mind when testing?

Comment: It would probably help if you would add as much detail as possible about the specific assay you're performing. As it stands know you can only get very general advice, and the answerers have to guess the details.